# How to generate large number of gaussian random variables in Swift

Tags: swift, random, lapack, accelerate-framework

I want to create a large array of random numbers drawn from the gaussian distribution. I found [dlarnv](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/dd1/group___o_t_h_e_rauxiliary_ga77e05a87ced667cbdb502aa87c72d056.html#ga77e05a87ced667cbdb502aa87c72d056), but I am not sure how to use it in Swift. Specifically, the type signature XCode shows is as follows:

```swift
dlarnv_(
__idist: UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_integer>,
__iseed: UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_integer>,
__n: UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_integer>,
__x: UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_doublereal>
)
```

How do I use this to fill an array with **single** precision floating point numbers? This is how far I have gotten:

```swift
n = 10000
var data: [Float]
data.reserveCapacity(n)

data
dlarnv_(
3, // for normal distribution
seed, // not sure how to seed
n,
data, // not sure how to pass a pointer
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a lot of values at one time, and you want them in a standard normal distribution (µ=0, σ=1), it's very hard to beat `dlarnv_`. But if you want a bit more flexibility, you should also consider GKLinearCongruentialRandomSource, and [a little math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform). The following is about 20% slower than `dlarnv_` for fetching 10M values all at once, but it's 5x faster if you want one value at a time (including adjusting the mean and stddev).

```
import GameplayKit
let random = GKLinearCongruentialRandomSource()

func randomNormalValue(average: Double, standardDeviation: Double) -> Double {
    let x1 = Double(random.nextUniform())
    let x2 = Double(random.nextUniform())
    let z1 = sqrt(-2 * log(x1)) * cos(2 * .pi * x2)

    return z1 * standardDeviation + average
}
```

I'm not sure why GKGaussianDistribution isn't implemented this way (or [one of the other solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Computational_methods) that are possibly even faster, but I haven't bothered to implement and test). I agree that it's slow.

But it's not *that* slow. It's about 75% slower than `dlarnv_` for 10M random values. Which is slow, but still in the same order-of-magnitude. The issue is the random source itself. Most folks write this:

```
let random = GKRandomSource()
```

And that's definitely the safest answer. But that's a cryptographically-secure source of entropy. If you're doing anything where the number needs to be *really* random, that's what you should be using (and `dlarnv_` doesn't do this, so it's unsafe in some cases).

But if you just need "kinda random, but no one is going to try to exploit the fact that it's not really random," the source you want is GKLinearCongruentialRandomSource. And that gets GKGaussianDistribution into the same ballpark as Accelerate (factor of 2, not orders of magnitude).

Comment: Box-Muller can produce 2 independent Gaussian’s per invocation. Add `z2 = sqrt(-2 * log(x1)) * sin(2 * .pi * x2)` to get the second one. Speed up the calculation of the pair `z1, z2` by pre-calculating the `sqrt()` term.

Comment: Oh, that's so true. I've stared at the "other" side of B-M forever and just thought "ok, who cares?" But you're definitely correct. That said, the big benefit of ignoring that is code simplicity. No need for extra logic to work out if another set of values is needed. But still, I should think about this more. I have some problems where I need hundreds to small thousands of random values, and maybe these approaches could make a tangible difference.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the random generator in Accelerate's BNNS library:

```
func randomFloats(n: Int,
                  mean: Float,
                  standardDeviation: Float) -> [Float] {
    
    let result = [Float](unsafeUninitializedCapacity: n) {
        
        buffer, unsafeUninitializedCapacity in
        
        guard
            var arrayDescriptor = BNNSNDArrayDescriptor(
                data: buffer,
                shape: .vector(n)),
            let randomNumberGenerator = BNNSCreateRandomGenerator(
                BNNSRandomGeneratorMethodAES_CTR,
                nil) else {
            fatalError()
        }
        
        BNNSRandomFillNormalFloat(
            randomNumberGenerator,
            &arrayDescriptor,
            mean,
            standardDeviation)
        
        unsafeUninitializedCapacity = n
        BNNSDestroyRandomGenerator(randomNumberGenerator)
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`dlarnv_`](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/dd1/group___o_t_h_e_rauxiliary_ga77e05a87ced667cbdb502aa87c72d056.html) is much faster than using `GameplayKit`

```swift
var n: Int32 = 500 // Array size
var d: Int32 = 3 // 3 for Normal(0, 1)
var seed: [Int32] = [1, 1, 1, 1] \\ Ideally pick a random seed
var x: [Double] = Array<Double>(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: Int(n)) { buffer, count in
    dlarnv_(&d, &seed, &n, buffer.baseAddress)
    count = Int(n)
}
```